# Error handling using try / catch inside async / await on firebase onCall cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await, try-catch, google-cloud-functions

I'm currently deploying this cloud function to my firebase app and I will be using the Node v8 runtime, so I can use the **async/await** syntax.

I'm having some trouble handling different kinds of errors that may occur in the same function.

When completed, the function should receive a **url** parameter to make request to that **url**, scrape the **response** body for some data and save it to the database. At this point, it is just returning the same url string that it received for testing purposes.

So far, this is what I have:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

exports.getDataFromUrl = functions.https.onCall((data) => {

  // PROMISIFIED REQUEST TO USE WITH ASYNC AWAIT
  const promisifiedRequest = function(options) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      request(options, (error, response, body) => {
        if (error) {
          return reject(error);
        }
        return resolve(response);
      });
    });
  };

  // CHECK IF URL IS PRESENT, IF NOT, THROW ERROR
  if (!data.url) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument','The URL parameter was invalid.');
  }

  // URL passed from the client.
  const url = data.url;

    // IIFE ASYNC FUNCTION
    (async function() {

      // TRY BLOCK
      try {

        // REQUEST OPTIONS TO THE URL
        const urlOptions = {
          url: 'https://www.someINEXISTENT.url',
          method: 'GET',
          gzip: true,
          headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.96 Safari/537.36'
          },
          jar: true
        };

        // CREATE RESPONSE AND CHEERIO OBJECT
        let response = null;
        let $ = null;

        // SEND REQUEST TO URL, AND PARSE WITH CHEERIO
        response = await promisifiedRequest(urlOptions);
        $ = cheerio.load(response.body);

      } // TRY BLOCK - END

      // CATCH BLOCK
      catch (error) {
        console.log('Caught an error: ' + error);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', error.message, error);
      }

      console.log('End of async function...');

    })()

  return {
    yourUrl : url
  };

});
```

My first error case, which happens when the URL is invalid is working just fine. The execution stops when I throw the following error:

`throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument','URL invalid.');`

As far as I understood, a need to throw this `HttpsError` in order to be able to catch in on the client. And it works. I get this error on the client, when it happens.

[image]

My problem is on the second type of error, which should be caught by the **try/catch** statement inside my **async function**. That error should happen when I try to request an inexistent url, for example.

What is happening is this (picture below):

The catch block is activated and I can see the `console.log() on my function console, but somehow it doesn't throw the error, and it complains about "throwing inside an async function without a catch block", even though I'm trowing it from inside a catch block. My client code does not get this error at all. From my client's perspective, the function completes without any errors.

[image]

Error:

> error: (node:5160) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   fnction without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not
>   handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

I have tried adding and outer `try/catch` blocks. And also using `.catch()` after the async IIFE to throw the error outside the async function, but it didn't solve the problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you have text of an error message to show, please copy that into the question itself instead of adding a screenshot.  Screenshots are difficult to read and impossible to search on SO.

Comment: Thanks. I'll edit and add that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...but somehow it doesn't throw the error...

That's because nothing uses the promise the `async` function creates, which is rejected by the `throw`. One of the rules of promises is: You must handle promise rejection or return the result to something else that will.

`functions.https.onCall` allows you to [return a promise](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.https#.onCall), so I'd make the callback an `async` function rather than using an async IIFE. You can't synchronously provide your result or throw an error, because you're dealing with an asynchronous operation.

Something along these lines (may need tweaking, and see `***` comments):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

// *** No reason to define this within `onCall`'s handler
const promisifiedRequest = function(options) {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    request(options, (error, response, body) => {
      if (error) {
        return reject(error);
      }
      return resolve(response);
    });
  });
};

exports.getDataFromUrl = functions.https.onCall(async (data) => { // *** Make it async, since `onCall` allows you to return a promise

  // CHECK IF URL IS PRESENT, IF NOT, THROW ERROR
  if (!data.url) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument','The URL parameter was invalid.');
  }

  // URL passed from the client.
  const url = data.url;

  // *** No need for try/catch unless you want to change the error
  // *** If you do, though, add it back and use `throw` in the `catch` block (as you did originally).
  // *** That will make the promise this async function returns reject.

  // REQUEST OPTIONS TO THE URL
  const urlOptions = {
    url: 'https://www.someINEXISTENT.url',
    method: 'GET',
    gzip: true,
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.96 Safari/537.36'
    },
    jar: true
  };

  // CREATE RESPONSE AND CHEERIO OBJECT
  let response = null;
  let $ = null;

  // SEND REQUEST TO URL, AND PARSE WITH CHEERIO
  response = await promisifiedRequest(urlOptions);
  $ = cheerio.load(response.body);

  // *** Do you really want to return the URL? Not something from the body of what you requested?
  return {
    yourUrl : url
  };
});
```

Comment: That worked! I just added a `try` block enclosing the `await` call. And then I threw the `error` from a `catch` block right before the return. I think that was necessary because I need to throw that error to stop the function and send the error to the client at that point. The url return at the end is just for testing purposes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @cbdev420 - Great! Glad that helped, I haven't done Firebase but the doc said you could return a promise, so... You don't need to catch and rethrow the error if you want to stop the function and send the error to the client at that point. You only need to catch and rethrow it if you want to throw a *different* error than the one already being thrown. Happy coding!

Comment: You are right! Firebase does throw (error code = INTERNAL) to my client even without a `catch` block. Although, in my function logs, it complains about the `Unhandled error` that happened. So I'd better handle it anyway. Since we're on the subject, I was thinking about handling errors in my function in a "always-success" manner, i.e.: Would catch the error but wouldn't throw an exception, I would successfully return an error object instead of the regular response and check for that on client side. The client would always go into the `.then()`. Do you see any (dis)advantages in either approach?

Comment: I'd double-check that result, if Firebase returns the error to your application, it's not unhandled, and there shouldn't be an unhandled rejection error. Re always returning success: I'm not a fan of doing that, in my view it's better to follow separate success vs. failure paths.

Comment: I'll follow your advice on that. Thanks a lot for your help!